# Could not find the main class

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

[image]

This is what i get when i try to run my program ..

I am also getting:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
```

Comment: You must be joking... where is the error stack trace?? I don't have 125 reputation otherwise I would have down voted it

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Comment: It seems your problem is not related to connecting to oracle, but to running your program. What steps are you doing for running this application (and how did you compile this). Be *precise* when you describe this.

Comment: and i always thought **Main** was the entry point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the comments you mention:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

This means that you are trying to use a class that was compiled for a newer version of Java on an older version.

You are probably trying to run this on Java 5 or older while you are using an Oracle JDBC driver JAR file that was compiled for Java 6.

Run it on a newer version of Java, or make sure you use a version of the Oracle JDBC driver that is supported on the Java version that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE is looking for main class to execute (i.e. it is trying to load java main) . try searching for setting and reset it with your class name or change class name to main.

and class name should start from CapitalLetter

Comment: that's actually irrelevant here. He seems to be either running his own classes against an older runtime than the compiler he was using, or he's trying to run them on an old JVM using a more modern Oracle driver (say a 1.5 JVM trying to run Oracle 11g drivers compiled for a Java 6 runtime).

Comment: @jwenting Agree, but I didn't notice OP's comment , it was probably posted after answered..